# Embedding code in presentations?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, openoffice.org

Not sure if this fits this forum, but can anyone recommend a good tool to embed code (with syntax highlighting) in presentations / office documents? Taking a screenshot is less than ideal. I'm using OpenOffice. Thanks.

Answer (score -4):

This is a poor question to ask on SO.  It is likely to result in your being told not to put source code in a presentation and other unhelpful advice.

Don't put source code in presentations, they are not an appropriate way of showing source code.

Comment: Huh? I just wanted to nicely display HTML/CSS/JS for a lecture I'm giving on webdev to non-webdevs. No need to get upset.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, and would really appreciate a solution here.